# Optimize MySql Query?

Tags: mysql, sql, optimization

I have the following query in an old database (MySql 5.7.16) that takes almost 45 seconds to run.
The table tbl_flightno has some 5 million records, the tbl_airline around 12,000. It seems the database is a bit at the limit, and every now and then there are some orphan records generated. I haven't found the culprit for that yet.

So I'm currently checking every now and then for those orphans and then fix them. I am wondering now, if there is a better way to search for those orphans.

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT N.World, N.AirlineCode) AS 'Orphans', COUNT(FlightNoID) AS 'Flights' 
FROM tbl_flightno N 
  LEFT JOIN tbl_airline A ON A.World = N.World AND A.AirlineCode = N.AirlineCode 
WHERE A.Airline IS NULL
```

However I'm not sure there is another, or better way.

Yes, updating the MySql version might benefit, also throwing more hardware would improve, but that would create much more work.

Thanks in advance for any hints.

EDIT: Added the additional information below:

Here is the EXPLAIN for the query.

```
    id  select_type table   partitions  type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    filtered    Extra
    1   SIMPLE      N       index       World_Airline   81      5217525 100 Using index
    1   SIMPLE      A       eq_ref   PRIMARY,VUnique,vWorld,vAirline,vReadOnly  PRIMARY 81  as.N.AirlineCode,as.N.World 1   10  Using where; Not exists
```

```
-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for tbl_airline
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tbl_airline`;
CREATE TABLE `tbl_airline` (
  `AirlineCode` int(8) NOT NULL,
  `World` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `Airline` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `Last_update` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `Destinations` int(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `NoFlights` int(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `CityPairs` int(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Headquarter` varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TZ` varchar(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ReadOnly` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Code` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Alliance` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Stock` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Country` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LegalHome` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Parent` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Director` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Founded` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `Rating` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`AirlineCode`,`World`),
  UNIQUE KEY `VUnique` (`World`,`AirlineCode`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `vWorld` (`World`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `vAirline` (`AirlineCode`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `vReadOnly` (`World`,`ReadOnly`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

```
-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for tbl_flightno
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tbl_flightno`;
CREATE TABLE `tbl_flightno` (
  `FlightNoID` bigint(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `FlightID` bigint(8) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `World` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `AirlineCode` int(8) NOT NULL,
  `FlightNo` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `Days` varchar(7) NOT NULL,
  `TimeDep` time NOT NULL,
  `TimeArr` time NOT NULL,
  `ActType` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
  `ActLink` varchar(6) NOT NULL,
  `Operator` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `Remarks` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Validity` varchar(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Distance` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Duration` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `Speed` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Via` int(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `AptFromC` varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AptDestC` varchar(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`FlightNoID`),
  UNIQUE KEY `FlightNoID` (`FlightNoID`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `World_Airline` (`World`,`AirlineCode`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `DepTimes` (`TimeDep`,`FlightID`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `FlightID` (`FlightID`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `Distance` (`World`,`AirlineCode`,`Distance`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `ActType` (`ActType`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `Via` (`Via`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `Remarks` (`World`,`Remarks`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `ActLink` (`ActLink`) USING BTREE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=25879501 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

Comment: Why would you need to *count* them? How does that help in fixing the inconsistencies?

Comment: Counting them let's me find out whether there are orphans or not. I need to know that there's a problem, before I can fix it, no? I have a similar query that then shows the actual records. That query is equally slow.

Comment: A good index could make all the difference. Remember you can make an index on more that one column. For instance, an index on `N.World` and `N.AirlineCode` could make `COUNT(DISTINCT N.World, N.AirlineCode)` work a lot faster.

Comment: I understand that, but if you *first* count, and then say "ah, there are some", and then still need to query *again* to get the actual records, you're wasting time.

Comment: counting is only required if you need to *know the count* - you just need *whether there are orphans or not* - which is not a count; use `not exists`

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Yes, I already have an index on the two fields World and AirlineCode.

Comment: @Stu It's a web based app and this counting query is used for a dashboard to show some KPIs. With this one, I know how many records there are. Once I see there are some, I will initiate the fix.

Comment: Off topic, but COUNT(DISTINCT N.World, N.AirlineCode) is not valid SQL. If those are string types you can concatenate them instead: COUNT(DISTINCT N.World || N.AirlineCode). Also, don't use string delimiter to quote identifiers. Here you probably don't need to quote them at all: AS Orphans and AS Flights.

Comment: For performance related questions always include ddl for tables, keys, indexes as well as an explain for the query.

Comment: @Lennart Thank, I added the table info and explain.

Comment: I normally don't use MySQL so I'm not 100% sure how to interpret the explain, but it appears to use indexes for both tables (you btw have a number of redundant ones). Can you try `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT N.World, N.AirlineCode) AS Orphans
     FROM tbl_flightno N WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM tbl_airline A 
    WHERE A.World = N.World 
      AND A.AirlineCode = N.AirlineCode
);`

Comment: Possibly redundant indexes: tbl_airline:
    KEY `vWorld` (`World`) USING BTREE  is covered by KEY VUnique
    KEY `vAirline` (`AirlineCode`) USING BTREE  is covered by PRIMARY KEY
 
    tbl_flightno
    UNIQUE KEY `FlightNoID` (`FlightNoID`) USING BTREE  is identical to PRIMARY KEY
    KEY `World_Airline` (`World`,`AirlineCode`) USING BTREE  is covered by KEY `Distance`

Comment: @Lennart Thanks for the pointing of the redundant indexes. I have deleted those and it seems the queries actually took advantage of that too. The initial query now finishes in some 16 seconds.

Comment: I have seen some - lets say - interesting behaviour. See for example: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/178313/what-strategy-does-mysql-optimizer-use-when-choosing-between-two-indexes

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT N.World, N.AirlineCode) AS Orphans
     , COUNT(CASE WHEN NOT EXISTS (
                 SELECT 1 FROM tbl_airline A 
                 WHERE A.World = N.World 
                   AND A.AirlineCode = N.AirlineCode
               ) THEN 1 
            END) AS Flights 
FROM tbl_flightno N;
```

Comment: I tried that, but this one timed out after more than 60 seconds. It seems that is even slower.

MySql has some deficits in query optimization it seems, cos sometimes I find with small changes big differences in query times. So I was hoping to find such a trick here.

Answer (score 0):

Your indexes are optimal and your query formulation is optimal.  The problem is that it needs 5M * 12K checks.

If it is I/O bound then, please provide table sizes and value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size` and the size of RAM.  with these, I may have advice on how to cut back on I/O.

[An aside]  There are several redundant indexes, but this won't impact the speed of that `SELECT`

```
PRIMARY KEY (`AirlineCode`,`World`),
UNIQUE KEY `VUnique` (`World`,`AirlineCode`) USING BTREE,
KEY `vWorld` (`World`) USING BTREE,
KEY `vAirline` (`AirlineCode`) USING BTREE,
KEY `vReadOnly` (`World`,`ReadOnly`) USING BTREE
```

-->

```
PRIMARY KEY (`AirlineCode`,`World`),
KEY (`World`,`AirlineCode`) USING BTREE,
KEY `vReadOnly` (`World`,`ReadOnly`) USING BTREE
```

In the other table, toss these two:

```
UNIQUE KEY `FlightNoID` (`FlightNoID`) USING BTREE,
KEY `World_Airline` (`World`,`AirlineCode`) USING BTREE,
```

"Rules":

- In MySQL `PRIMARY KEY` is a `UNIQUE` key.
- When you have `INDEX(a,b)`, `INDEX(a)` is unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I have already reduced the various indexes.

- The `innodb_buffer_pool_size` is currently 6,442,450,944
- `tbl_airline` has an Index Length of 720.00 KB, and a Data Length of 4.02 MB
- `tbl_flightno` has an Index Length of 1.03 GB and a Data Length of 746.38 MB
- The webserver has 16 GB of RAM. 

It's quite an old machine by now.

Comment: The Task Manager on the server shows 10.5 GB of used RAM, with some 5.4 GB available.